# Is it possible to assign different colors to parts of an .obj file?

Tags: graphics3d

There are four different cubes in [an .obj file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dmpctrlwsypq0cw/4cubes.obj?dl=0). After loaded into Mathematica, is it possible to assign four random colors to the cubes?

```
 (* assuming the .obj file was loaded in the c: root *)
 cubes = Import["c:\\4cubes.obj"] ;
 Graphics3D[  First[cubes]  ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
gr = Import["...\4cubes.obj",  "GraphicsComplex"];

Graphics3D[gr] /. Polygon[x_] :> ({Hue[RandomReal[]], Polygon[#]} & /@ Partition[x, 6])
```

[image]

```
alltextures = ExampleData /@ ExampleData["ColorTexture"];
alltextures = alltextures /. $Failed -> Sequence[];
tc = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}};

Graphics3D[gr] /. Polygon[x_] :> 
        ({Texture[ImageMultiply[RandomChoice[alltextures], Hue[RandomReal[]]]], 
          Polygon[#, VertexTextureCoordinates -> Table[tc, {6}]]} & /@ 
     Partition[x, 6])
```

[image]

To assign specific colors:

```
col = {Red, Blue, Orange, Green};
Graphics3D[gr] /. Polygon[x_] :> ({#, Polygon[#2]} & @@@ Transpose[{col, Partition[x, 6]}])
```

[image]

**Update: Dealing with more general polyhedra**

```
grb = Import["...\\4shapes.obj", "GraphicsComplex"];
Graphics3D[grb]
```

[image]

**Approach:** Form a graph using the polygons as the vertex set. Two polygons are connected if they share one or more vertices. `ConnectedComponents` of the resulting graph are the polyhedral objects we seek to identify.

Note: We work with `Graphics` using `Normal@grb`. An approach using `GraphicsComplex` failed because the vertex coordinate list has duplicates which prevents working with the indices to identify neighboring polygons.

```
polygons = Join @@ (Normal[grb] /. HoldPattern[VertexNormals -> _] :> Sequence[]);
polygons = polygons /. Polygon -> Sequence;
edges = DeleteDuplicates[UndirectedEdge @@@ 
          Map[ToString, Select[Subsets[polygons, {2}], Intersection @@ # =!= {} &], {-2}]];
Graph[edges]
```

[image]

```
connectedcomps = Map[ToExpression, ConnectedComponents[Graph[edges]], {-1}];
Graphics3D[{Hue[RandomReal[]], Polygon[#]} & /@ connectedcomps, Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image]

```
Graphics3D[({Texture[ImageMultiply[RandomChoice[alltextures], Hue[RandomReal[]]]], 
            Polygon[#,  VertexTextureCoordinates -> 
                  Table[tc[[;; Max[Length /@ #]]], {Length@#}]]} & /@ connectedcomps), 
          Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answers. I would like to ask one more thing, how to modify your answer to deal with .obj file with different shapes like [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/a3kw1rh6t8wfdh8/4shapes.obj?dl=0)?

Comment: @Putterboy, I was afraid "this" was coming:) Even in the specific case of `4cubes`, it was pure luck that the single `Polygon` in the `GraphicsComplex` contained the faces in a particular order so that `Partition[...,6]` gave the cubes we needed. For general shapes, I can't think of any approach  that can identify arbitrary collection of shapes in a set of polygons. Great question btw...

Answer (score 2):

I have just figured out a manual way to get the job done, although a bit clumsy, I think it is still worth posting it.

[image]

```
(* assuming the .obj file was loaded in the c: root *)
gr = Import["c:\\4shapes.obj", "GraphicsComplex"]  ;
Clear[a, b, c, d, x, y, z, ca, cb, cc, cd, ce, cf, cg ];
{ca, cb, cc, cd, ce, cf, cg} = {Red, Blue, Yellow, Green, Gray, Cyan, Orange};
space = 5;
verts = gr[[1]];
L1 = (gr[[2]][[1]] /. Polygon -> List)[[1]]  ;
L2 = (gr[[2]][[2]] /. Polygon -> List) [[1]];
vNum1 = Length[L1];
vNum2 = Length[L2];

Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[verts, {
    If[aB, {ca, Polygon[Take[L1, {1, a}] ]}, {}],
    If[bB, {cb, Polygon[Take[L1, {a + 1, b}] ]}, {}],
    If[cB, {cc, Polygon[Take[L1, {b + 1 , c }] ]}, {}],
    If[dB, {cd, Polygon[Take[L1, {c + 1 , d}] ]}, {}],
    If[xB, {ce, Polygon[Take[L2, {1 , x }] ]} , {}] ,
    If[yB, {cf, Polygon[Take[L2, {x + 1 , y }] ]} , {}] ,
    If[zB, {cg, Polygon[Take[L2, {y + 1 , z }] ]} , {}] 
    }]],

 Grid[{
   {
    ColorSetter[Dynamic[ca], ImageSize -> {20, 20}],
    Control[{{aB, True, ""}, {True -> "show", False -> "hide"}, 
      ControlType -> RadioButtonBar}],
    Spacer[space],
    Control[{{a, 2, "Shape 1"}, 1, vNum1, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}] 
    },
   {
    ColorSetter[Dynamic[cb], ImageSize -> {20, 20}],
    Control[{{bB, True, ""}, {True -> "show", False -> "hide"}, 
      ControlType -> RadioButtonBar}],
    Spacer[space],
    Control[{{b, a, "Shape 2"}, a, vNum1, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}] 
    },
   {
    ColorSetter[Dynamic[cc], ImageSize -> {20, 20}],
    Control[{{cB, True, ""}, {True -> "show", False -> "hide"}, 
      ControlType -> RadioButtonBar}],
    Spacer[space],
    Control[{{c, b, "Shape 3"}, b, vNum1, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}] 
    } ,
   {
    ColorSetter[Dynamic[cd], ImageSize -> {20, 20}],
    Control[{{dB, False, ""}, {True -> "show", False -> "hide"}, 
      ControlType -> RadioButtonBar}],
    Spacer[space],
    Control[{{d, c, "Shape 4"}, 1, vNum1, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}] 
    }  ,
   {
    ColorSetter[Dynamic[ce], ImageSize -> {20, 20}],
    Control[{{xB, False, ""}, {True -> "show", False -> "hide"}, 
      ControlType -> RadioButtonBar}],
    Spacer[space],
    Control[{{x, 2, "Shape 5"}, 1, vNum2, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}] 
    }  ,
   {
    ColorSetter[Dynamic[cf], ImageSize -> {20, 20}],
    Control[{{yB, False, ""}, {True -> "show", False -> "hide"}, 
      ControlType -> RadioButtonBar}],
    Spacer[space],
    Control[{{y, x, "Shape 6"}, x, vNum2, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}] 
    }  ,
   {
    ColorSetter[Dynamic[cg], ImageSize -> {20, 20}],
    Control[{{zB, False, ""}, {True -> "show", False -> "hide"}, 
      ControlType -> RadioButtonBar}],
    Spacer[space],
    Control[{{z, vNum2, "Shape 7"}, y, vNum2, 1, 
      Appearance -> "Labeled"}] 
    }  
   }]
 ]
```

The link for the obj file: ***[Click here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/a3kw1rh6t8wfdh8/4shapes.obj?dl=0)***