# How to color objects from a single .obj file?

Tags: graphics3d

How to paint the dolphin, shark and the box with different colors after loading the `.obj` file into Mathematica?

```
gr = Import["c:\\DolphinSharkBox.obj" ];
Graphics3D[gr[[1]]]
```

[Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/q8tg06j8m01bdcs/DolphinSharkBox.obj?dl=0) for the `.obj` file.
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The imperceptiple smile of your shark hides 12 triples of teeth and a pair eyes each with 288 lenses!

[image]

I use the method in the update to [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/58841/125) as is:

```
grc = Import["... \\DophinSharkBox.obj",  "GraphicsComplex"];
Graphics3D[grc]
```

[image]

Producing the graph takes a while (perhaps could be faster with `Pick` instead of `Select`):

```
polygonsc = Join @@ (Normal[grc] /. 
     HoldPattern[VertexNormals -> _] :> Sequence[]);
polygonsc = polygonsc /. Polygon -> Sequence;
edgesc =  DeleteDuplicates[UndirectedEdge @@@ Map[ToString,
     Select[Subsets[polygonsc, {2}], Intersection @@ # =!= {} &], {-2}]];
```

Expecting three connected components we get 41:

```
cc =  Map[ToExpression, ConnectedComponents[Graph[edgesc]], {-1}];
Through@{Length@# &, Tally[Length /@ #] &}@ cc
(* {41, {{3804, 1}, {952, 1}, {288, 2}, {38, 24}, {28, 12}, {6, 1}}} *)

Graph[edgesc, VertexStyle -> White, VertexSize -> .005, VertexShapeFunction -> "Point", 
     EdgeStyle -> Directive[Opacity[.5], Thin, Hue[.35, .5, .8]], 
     Background -> Black, EdgeShapeFunction -> (Line[#1] &), ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

```
Graphics3D[({EdgeForm[], Hue[RandomReal[]], Polygon@#} & /@ cc), Lighting ->"Neutral"]
```

[image]

Two largest components:

```
Graphics3D[({EdgeForm[], Hue[RandomReal[]], Polygon@# }&/@cc[[;;2]]), Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image]

and the anatomic details at the top picture produced by

```
Graphics3D[({EdgeForm[],Hue[RandomReal[]],Polygon@#}&/@ cc[[3;;-2]]), Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

Note: I eliminated `VertexNormals` to focus on the polygon faces. The method can be modified to keep the `VertexNormals` to produce smoother surfaces.

Comment: Much can be learned from your answers, Thanks again. I just wondered, is your method can be modified to produce a UV mapping for use of 3d model texturing in Mathematica?

Comment: Thank you @Putterboy. I need to google what `UV mapping` is :)

Comment: ... ah, I see. Perhaps `ListSurfacePlot3D` as in [Texture>>Applications>>Marble Bunny](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Texture.html) could work for the bodies of your shark and dolphin.

Comment: The reason why I had such idea came up because the graph images of your solution look very much the same as the spreaded mesh that the 3D guys used for their photo realistic texturing.

The 3D guys cut and spread their modeled object's mesh flat, and then paste a photo image of the real object to the various mesh parts of the object accordingly, in order to obtain a photo realistic looking of their final model.